# What else should I eat besides my post workout shake?

Tags: workout, weight-gain, muscle-mass, muscle-gain

I am starting a 12-Week program to gain muscle mass and weight. I'm taking Dymatize Elite Mass High-protein muscle gainer as a supplement. I take one scoop before workout and two scoops along with a fruit after workout. I would like to know what else should I consume to maximize my gains besides my post workout shake because I don't know whether it is enough to drink my shake along with a fruit and then wait for lunch.

Thank you! 
This is the 12-week program by Jim Stoppani http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/shortcut-to-size.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foundation of any good diet to make “gains” (build muscle mass) is high quality complex carbohydrates. I.E. oatmeal, sweat potatoes, yams, pumpkins, squash, brown rice, rice.  Notice a starch that I left out? Corn. Corn in an unprocessed form is virtual indigestible by humans.

Dymatize Elite Mass High-protein muscle gainer primary carbohydrate source is Maltodextrin. *“Maltodextrin can be enzymatically derived from any starch. In the US, this starch is usually corn” This product’s Supplement Facts list 75g of Total Carbohydrate 8g as Sugars.  Maltodextrin a heavily processed corn product that while technical not a sugar it is processed very similar to sugar. *“Maltodextrin is easily digestible, being absorbed as rapidly as glucose”.

Taking Dymatize Elite Mass High-protein muscle gainer before your work out is going to cause a sharp insulin response during your work out which is not what you want.  This product is meant to be taken after a workout not before.

To answer your question about “what else should I consume to maximize my gains?”

- Consume high quality complex carbohydrates early in the day before
  you work out
- Avoid all easily digestible Carbohydrates (sugur, Maltodextrin,
  Maltose, corn surup) before your work out.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltodextrin *

Answer (score 2):

Timing isn't as important as you may think. The 'Anabolic Window' has been proven a myth ([see here](http://breakingmuscle.com/nutrition/is-the-anabolic-window-a-myth) for a study). Instead, calculate your total calories for the day and find out where you are. Estimate your sustainable caloric intake - the amount of calories to neither lose nor gain weight - and add 500 to that. Ask yourself other things like:

What else am I eating?
How many grams of protein/carbs/fat/sugar am I taking in each day?
What are the ingredients of what I'm eating?

Nutrition weighs heavily on the results you'll receive from working out. I've always been hesitant to take 'gainer' supplements as most of them are full of sugar and leave me feeling bloated. Another thing to consider is the amount of *real food* you're taking in. If the gainer keeps you full for such a long time that you aren't able to eat enough real food, I would cut back on its usage.

As for what else to eat, bodybuilding.com has [an entire meal plan](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/mohr60.htm) laid out that may give you some ideas. Knowledge is key, do as much research as you can about nutrition and the way our body processes food. Hope this helps!

Comment: Not to mention that mass gainers tend to be overly expensive (at least more so than a normal protein supp.).